"I'm dazzled by your shining beauty"
Does it sound awkward in English to compliment a woman by saying something like

I'm dazzled by your shining beauty

Does portraying someone's beauty as the light that shines carry any weirdness?

"Shining" is redundant here. Dazzle already bears the connotation of light that is too strong for the naked eye. To be dazzled by someone's beauty is commonly used in English.

@fev that's all I wanted to know, thank you.

As to whether it's weird, that totally depends on context. It might be considered a bit much. I'd avoid it outside of something like a wedding ceremony.
